# "Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation" error when using Registry.SetValue

Tags: vb.net, registry

I attempted to make a program in VB.NET that would add itself to startup in the Windows registry. However, when I run the program I receive this error message:

> Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.

I have attempted to change permissions and used many methods online but they all proved to be unsuccessful. I just do not seem to have the permission to interfere in the registry.

**Here is my code:**

```
My.Computer.Registry.SetValue("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run", "FILENAME", "FILEPATH")
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Side note: always give the user the option to willingly add your application to startup, and the option to reverse that. **Don't force your application to run at startup without the user's permission**.

Comment: Just about anything in HKEY_CURRENT_USER is writable without needing special permissions. Rather than permissions, I suspect the problem here is you need to get the key (or open the subkey), and set the value on the key, rather than just calling SetValue() on a long path.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I've seen many tutorials on youtube but they do not include user permission and they still work. Please refer to these videos: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=baXyf-jlGm4

Comment: @EricCartman Getting permission from the user is about good practice and UX, rather than anything technical.

Comment: Thats the trouble with youtube "tutorials"; they rarely tell you any of the peripheral issues you should be aware of.

Answer (score 2):

As Joel stated in the comments, you should open the subkey first, and then set the value.

Here's the methods I usually use to add/remove my programs to/from Windows startup:

```
Public Sub AddToStartup(Optional appCommand As String = "")
    Dim applicationName As String = Application.ProductName
    Dim applicationPath As String = Application.ExecutablePath
    Dim regKey As Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey
    regKey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run", True)
    regKey.SetValue(applicationName, """" & applicationPath & """" & appCommand)
    regKey.Close()
End Sub

Public Sub RemoveFromStartup()
    Dim applicationName As String = Application.ProductName
    Dim regKey As Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey
    regKey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run", True)
    regKey.DeleteValue(applicationName, False)
    regKey.Close()
End Sub
```

I use an Optional parameter (i.e., `appCommand`) in `AddToStartup` method in case I wanted to pass a command argument to the instance that runs at Windows startup. For example `" -Hide"` to hide the program in tray when running at startup.

**Side note:** always give the user the option to willingly add your application to startup, and the option to reverse that. ***Do not force your application to run at startup without the user's permission***, otherwise the user will hate you :)

Comment: Thanks to all responses, they were much appreciated and very informative! :) (Ahmed, Joel and Plutonix)   What I meant previously @ Joel was that interference with the registry seemed to work without requiring user permission so I was curious to why this was possible; I agree that user permission must be given at first. Once again thanks to all responses :)

Comment: I just encountered another problem! (I hope you are not fed up with me!). I initially wanted to use a different name and executable path when adding the regkey. Using the Application.ProductName and Application.ExecutablePath works when I run the program but I wish to add a file with a different pathway to the startup, not the original exe file that is being run. So when I intend to use a different executable pathway/name, I still get the same error: "Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation". Do you know why this could be?

Comment: What I aim to do is that when the program is executed, it copies itself to a certain location and the new file location of the copied file is added to startup - just some more context behind this...

Comment: @EricCartman Replace the first two lines in the first method with `Dim applicationName As String = "YourAppName"` and `Dim applicationPath As String = "..\Folder\SubFolder\YourApp.exe"`, do not change anything else in this method, and it should work fine. Is that what you did? Please double-check.

Comment: Hi Ahmed, I did exactly as you showed in the method and the problem lies within the file location itself. I used the Application.ProductName and Application.ExecutablePath and it worked perfectly. It added itself to startup and as I restarted the computer the program ran at startup as it should have. However, when I used a different file location and a different name, it did add itself to startup, but as I restarted the computer, it removed itself from the startup folder in regedit on it's own and didn't execute. So I tried to run the program afterwards and the same error appeared...

Comment: More information: I used the file name "host" and the file location ""c:\users\" + Environment.UserName.ToString + "\host.exe". Any file location other than "Application.ExecutablePath" does NOT work :(

Comment: @EricCartman If it **did** add the path of the other executable to the registry, that means it worked. If the registry key got removed *after it's been added using this code*, that means it got removed by something else (e.g., antivirus, another program, the same program that's been added to startup,.. etc). How is that related to the original issue? Unless the file didn't get added to the registry in the first place?

Comment: If the antivirus was responsible for removing the program from startup, then it should have removed the "Application.ExecutablePath" as well as the "c:\users\\host.exe" pathway. The use of Application.ExecutablePath worked perfectly fine and the exe file executed at startup as expected. BUT when I use the exe file that uses "c:\users\\host.exe" pathway, it adds itself to registry but when I restart the computer it is no longer present in the registry (It just magically disappears!) and when I run the exe program again it says the original error:"Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation"