# Start with windows without requiring administrative rights

Tags: vb.net, startup, startup-folder, system-startup

I know the commonly used method to run a program at start-up is put the application path in the currentversion/run key of windows registry. But doing so requires the program to run with administrative privileges (Run as administrator).
I've seen some commercial applications, whose program has an option to run during windows startup but these programs donot require to run in administrator mode. I think these programs donot make use of registery but use some other method to make the program to run during startup.

Comment: Accessing the `CurrentVersion\Run` key under `HKCU` does _not_ require administrative privileges nor the application would be started with admin privileges if it doesn't require it. Perhaps you're using the `Run` key under `HKLM` instead? Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46899228/4934172).

Comment: I don't see Vb.net, also, where is the question

Comment: @EssKay Regarding your suggested edit: The question targets VB.NET even if it doesn't include VB code (which could make it too broad) but removing the [vb.net] tag doesn't help either; it just makes the question even broader because it doesn't target a specific language.